# Getting a window to the top in wxPython for Mac

Tags: macos, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have an app that lives in the tray, and I'm trying to get it to show/hide when you click a certain menu item in the tray menu. The code almost works, but the window shows up behind other windows, instead of on top like it should. (Note, I don't want it to be always-on-top, just to pop to the top of the window stack.)

It seems to work on Windows just fine, but on Mac it stays below whatever other windows have been pulled in front of it in the mean time.

The relevant code is below.

```
def on_hide_frame(self, event):
    self.frame.on_iconify(event)

def on_restore_frame(self, event):
    if self.frame.IsIconized():
        self.frame.Iconize(False)
    if not self.frame.IsShown():
        self.frame.Show(True)
    self.frame.Raise()
```

Also note that, when this is called, `self.frame` is the same object as `app.GetTopWindow()` and interchanging the two does not fix the bug.

Comment: Thats exactly the same block of code I use to show my app and it works for me on mac, maybe check that the methods being called when you expect. The other windows dont have always on top or float on parent do they?

Comment: There's no other always on top, the other windows could be Chrome or Terminal, doesn't really matter. I'll look into float on parent, but this should be the main window...

Comment: Nope, it is the top window, with no parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the cause is that the app is a background app, and thus needs an activate event. It may not be the best way, but it's fairly easy to send yourself an activate event using Applescript:

```
subprocess.Popen(['osascript', '-e', '''\
    tell application "System Events"
      set procName to name of first process whose unix id is %s
    end tell
    tell application procName to activate
''' % os.getpid()])
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint, which looks great. I will try this.