# In wxPython, how do you send your own app an activate signal?

Tags: python, wxpython

As [with this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/wxpython-users/XA-W4YfWD-s/smTAOmO5p-YJ) on the wxPython mailing list, I'm developing a tray application that needs to have its Preference pane pop straight to the top above any other windows (especially). This is apparently because the application is backgrounded and needs to be activated.

How can a widget send an activate event to the main application?

```
def show_preferences(self, event):
    self.frame.Iconize(False)
    self.frame.Show()
    self.frame.Raise()
```

but this doesn't quite do the job in Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I found a really hacky way to do it in another StackOverflow answer here:

- [Getting a window to the top in wxPython for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901067/getting-a-window-to-the-top-in-wxpython-for-mac)

It uses AppleScript and subprocess.

There is also an interesting discussion on Apple's HIG and how wxPython follows it here:

- http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/OS-X-issue-raising-minimized-frame-td2371601.html

I don't quite follow all the talk on there, but it kind of sounds like Apple may not allow you to set an app to be TopLevel when it's minimized or hidden.